# How do I make a "div" element pop up and darken the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

All-right, I've been looking around a few sites and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EtHbf/1/) is the closest to what I want, kinda.

I want a button to make a `div` show up, (I can do this via a spoiler code I have),
Then I want the same button to dim the screen like in the link above, now what I -Can't- do. is make this a toggle button. i might be missing something basic but I don't know.

here below I have html with a button that will show up a `div` with "hello" in it, I want it so when "hello" pops up it will dim the screen, but pressing the button again (Or) clicking out of the `div`, will return the screen to normal again.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="if(document.getElementById('spoiler-') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('spoiler-') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('spoiler-') .style.display='none'}">Spoiler</button>
  <div id="spoiler-" style="display:none">
    <p style="border: 2px solid gray;">Hello!</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for taking time to read this. hope to figure this out soon >_<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I begin I would like to remind you not to use inline JS or CSS, it's bad practice, not very easy to read and you should always separate your HTML, CSS & JS.

Now on to your question, instead of reinventing the wheel you might want to take a look at this really neat framework called [BootStrap](http://getbootstrap.com).

Add these links and scripts in your head file:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
<!-- We need jQuery to make bootstrap.min.js work -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a working example of a BootStrap modal:

```js
$("#myModal").on("show.bs.modal", function(event) {
  console.log("Modal has been shown, do something amazing now!");
});
```

```css
.modal-backdrop {
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
<!-- We need jQuery to make bootstrap.min.js work -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" id="modalOne">Button</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem.
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">OK</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also change the background colour, by changing the `background-color` property underneath the `.modal-backdrop` class in your CSS.

If you need extra help with [BootStrap](http://getbootstrap.com), you can head [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) to get started with BootStrap.

Good luck and all the best.

Comment: please a example functional

Comment: @x-rw What do you mean by that?

Comment: I will have to play with the CSS and such but this is almost perfect to what i had in mind, thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @Smokezarn Anytime! Also if it helped don't forget to up-vote, thanks.

Comment: Oh, so i added everything into a test doc to get the CSS right, and it turns out that adding the BootStrap links wig out the rest of my CSS when i add it to the page i want it on. But i think its because i manually made a bunch of divs sit side by side. so i think it should be easy to reset them